# Html5 video width and height when changing the browser size

Tags: php, html5-video

I am using html5 video, The video is playing fine but  when we change  the width of the browser, the width of the video scales, but the height doesnot get height. They both need to scale uniformly to keep the original height x width ratio the same. Kindly suggest us.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 video is only play with it's own resolution. That is if you are playing a video with 600x200 resolution, when you change width of browser which video only play with resolution ratio of 6:2.

Comment: How to set the full height and width of the browser size?

Comment: That you need to apply height and with by percentage.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't post your HTML or CSS, here's a good guess. Set the `height` of the video to `auto` and it will scale and keep its aspect ratio when changing the width of the window:

```
<video width="50%" height="auto" controls>
    <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_480p.mov" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/a46g8/) (with 50% width)
[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/23asj/) (width 100% width)